# How to share photos with iOS users if you don't own any Apple products

Tags: photos, sharing

I have a bunch of family members with iPads. I'd like to share picture streams with them. But I don't want to buy any Apple products, thus no icloud access for me. I have pro accounts for dropbox and 2 other services like that, Amazon CloudDrive, etc. But nothing seems to be providing anything other than a download link, that ipad users simply cannot import into their pic library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your friends sign you up for a free iCloud account using their device.

Once you have a username/password in iCloud, you can upload photos and share things quite well using the web app.

- https://icloud.com

There isn't a provision to pay for iCloud - so you need to sign up on the coattails of a hardware purchase.

Comment: I think this is the best option. Is there a limit to the number of accounts you can create per device? I mean, I only need one account, but still. Also I wonder whether I should script something to upload via the web interface or whether that windows client would actually work for keeping pictures synced. Or how about creating an IFTTT that saves pics from my dropbox to that icloud account with the shared album?